# как проверить имеет ли процесс GUI?

Tags: python, gui

допустим есть вот такой цикл:`for proc in psutil.process_iter():`
как проверить, имеет ли `proc` GUI, и можно ли вообще получить чисто список программ имеющих GUI?
P.S: нужно получать только запущенные процессы испольщующие GUI

Comment: в данном вопросе хорошо бы уточнить операционную систему.

Comment: windows 10, но было бы желательно чтоб работало и на windows 11

Comment: посмотрите на этот код https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11711417/get-hwnd-by-process-id-c - там берется список всех окон, потом у каждого окна спрашивается хендл процесса. В конце у Вас есть хендлы процессов, которые имеют GUI

Comment: но вить там c++, а мне нужен Python код

Comment: я знаю. Поэтому, я описал и словами.

Comment: никто не запрещает использовать модули win32api и ctypes

Comment: @KoVadim как сформировать второй параметр для EnumWindows? m_ProcessId это не int....

Comment: если я правильно помню, то он там LPARAM, а это 32/64битное число (в зависимости от платформы). Так что да, это не совсем int, но все же

Comment: LPARAM...  в том ответе туда как-будто запихнули pid, я вот к чему.

Comment: вроде понял... второй элемент колбэка. контекст так сказать. в питоне не нужен - тут есть замыкания..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Принцип один и тот же: спрашиваем ОС информацию обо всех окнах и достаем из окна pid. По функции winpids уже получишь список процессов и process_iter уже не нужна, но оставил для примера.

## Xorg (Linux):

Установка

```
pip3 install python-xlib psutil
```

Код:

```
def winpids():

    from Xlib import display
    from Xlib.X import AnyPropertyType
    from Xlib.protocol.request import InternAtom

    root = display.Display().screen().root
    query = root.query_tree()

    for window in query.children:
        atom = InternAtom(display=window.display, name="_NET_WM_PID", only_if_exists=1)
        pid = window.get_property(atom.atom, AnyPropertyType, 0, 10)
        if pid:
            pid = pid.value.tolist()[0]
            yield pid
        

def procs():
    import psutil
    
    guiprocs = set(winpids())
    
    for proc in psutil.process_iter():
        if proc.pid in guiprocs:
            print( proc )

procs()
```

## Win32 (Windows):

Проверял python3.10, pywin32-304, windows 11.

Установка

```
pip install pywin32 psutil
```

Хотя pywin32 лучше ставить через установщик https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/releases/

Код

```
def winpids():
    import win32gui
    import win32process

    pids = []
    def winEnumHandler(hwnd, ctx):
        pid = win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd)
        pids.append(pid[1])
    win32gui.EnumWindows(winEnumHandler, None)
    return pids

def procs():
    import psutil

    guiprocs = set(winpids())

    for proc in psutil.process_iter():
        if proc.pid in guiprocs:
            print( proc )


procs()
```

На Виндовс возможно ещё есть что-то через COM.